# PHP array_udiff weird behavior

Tags: php, arrays, comparison

I have 2 arrays, `$array0` and `$array1`. Let's pre-fill them:

```
$user01 = array("no" => 1, "name" => "john");
$user02 = array("no" => 2, "name" => "lewis");
$user03 = array("no" => 3, "name" => "dan");

$array0 = array($user01, $user02, $user03, $user04);

$user11 = array("id" => 1, "name" => "john", "attr" => "foo");
$user12 = array("id" => 7, "name" => "mark", "attr" => "bar");

$array1 = array($user11, $user12);
```

I want to get all users from `$array0` who are not in `$array1`, so I use `array_udiff`:

```
$diff = array_udiff($array0, $array1, function ($userA, $userB) {
  return $userA['no'] == $userB['id'];
});
```

However, inside the anonymous compare function, if I do a `var_dump` of `$userA` and `$userB`, they both seem to belong to `$array0`, while the behavior I was expecting is for `$userA` to belong to `$array0` and `$userB` to `$array1`.

I.e., the expected answer is `[[2, "lewis"], [3, "dan"]]`, but I get a 'not found index': "Undefined index `id`" in the line of the comparison function.

Am I missing something on `array_udiff` behavior?

Comment: Try to return integers: 0 for equal numbers, 1 if number from `$array0` is bigger than number from `$array1` and analog -1 if opposite is happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I'm pretty sure PHP expects the arguments to the comparison function to be interchangeable, you either need to change the array indexes to be common, or implement logic in the comparison function to deal with this.
2. That's not how a comparison function works.

   > The comparison function must return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if the first argument is considered to be respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

So:

```
$user01 = array("id" => 1, "name" => "john");  // "no" changed to "id"
$user02 = array("id" => 2, "name" => "lewis");
$user03 = array("id" => 3, "name" => "dan");

$array0 = array($user01, $user02, $user03); // non-existant $user04 removed

$user11 = array("id" => 1, "name" => "john", "attr" => "foo");
$user12 = array("id" => 7, "name" => "mark", "attr" => "bar");

$array1 = array($user11, $user12);

$diff = array_udiff($array0, $array1, function ($userA, $userB) {
    if( $userA['id'] == $userB['id'] ) { return 0; }  // compare function re-jiggered
    else { return $userA['id'] - $userB['id']; }
});

print_r($diff);
```

Yields:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => lewis
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => dan
        )

)
```